# Sitecore 9.0 Forms location can not be specified during creation

Tags: sitecore-forms

When we create any form in Sitecore 9.0 , it stores them under path /sitecore/Forms.

I need to specify particular path during creation of form.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to have different location of root Forms item, this is possible. 
Forms root item is referenced in various places in `core` database and you just need to change this reference to your new item.

These are the items in `core` db that you need to change:

- SearchConfig: {60F35FD9-88CB-4DF5-8E78-1E9BF5FE181C}
- AllFormsSearchConfig: {60F35FD9-88CB-4DF5-8E78-1E9BF5FE181C}

See these blog post for further details:

- https://sitecoresandbox.com/2018/03/09/there-are-no-forms-to-display-in-sitecore-9-forms-designer/
- https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/03/30/best-practices-on-sitecore-9-forms-for-development-teams/

If you would like to specify this path during each form creation, that is I am afraid not possible as this item in referenced from `core` db and needs to be always the same.

Some changes will be done with Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8 where you can create forms specific to sites where they were created. But don't know whether it will be feature of SXA 1.8 or Sitecore 9.1 itself. Will update this answer once it's out and I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Prochazkas useful information.

Comment: @siddharth please mark correct answer if Peter answer fix your issue.